# How to create a dummy function in H2 embbeded db for integration test

Tags: spring-boot, h2, spring-test

I have a spring boot application that connects to an oracle database. The project contains a service class (userService) that calls the function `VALIDATEUSER(USERNAME IN VARCHAR2,PASSWD IN VARCHAR2)` in oracle and return 1 if user is valid and 0 invalid.

I need to create the same function  in h2 db that always return true for my integration test.

Basically I wanted to created the function in sql script and load it during integration test as follows:

```
@Test
@Sql(scripts={"classpath:/sql/createFunction.sql"})
public void testUserInfo() throws Exception {

//  userService calls   VALIDATEUSER function
userService.isUserValid("testdb", "testdb");
 
}
```

How to create the function VALIDATEUSER in h2?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can execute the following SQL in H2 to create a function that accepts two `VARCHAR` parameters and returns an `INTEGER` result 1.

```sql
CREATE ALIAS VALIDATEUSER AS $$int validateUser(String name, String password) { return 1; }$$
```

Comment: Thnks i have added the script but got this error: CREATE ALIAS VALIDATEUSER AS $$int validateUser(String name, String password) { return 1; nested exception is org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException: Syntax error in SQL statement "CREATE ALIAS VALIDATEUSER AS [*]$$int validateUser(String name, String password) { return 1" [42000-200]

Comment: It looks like you copied only part of the command from my answer. You missed `; }$$` at the and.

Comment: Thanks for the remarks it looks like the issue is with spring ScriptUtils class which is using semi colon as separator thus not executing the whole sql

Comment: You can try to use `CREATE ALIAS VALIDATEUSER AS 'int validateUser(String name, String password) { return 1; }'` instead. But if it isn't able to parse `;` inside standard character string literals too, add some `public` class with such `public static` method to the classpath and use `CREATE ALIAS VALIDATEUSER FOR "full.class.Name.staticMethodName"`.

Comment: Thanks oCREATE ALIAS VALIDATEUSER AS 'int validateUser(String name, String password) { return 1; }' works for me. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
CREATE ALIAS functionName AS 'int methodName(String name, String password) { return 1; }'
```

in Java you can use like this

```
    Class.forName("org.h2.Driver");
    Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(
            "jdbc:h2:mem:", "sa", "");
    Statement stat = conn.createStatement();

    // Using a custom Java function

    stat.execute("CREATE ALIAS functionName AS 'int methodName(String name, String password) { return 1; }' ");

    stat.close();
    conn.close();
```